# Somewhere [object Object] is printed

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

I have a couple of gulp tasks running and upon completion, just when gulp is about to exit, `[object Object]` is printed to the console.

No idea where this comes from. No idea if this is a gulp issue or caused by a module.

Overwriting `console.log` did not help because `[object Object]` is already printed as a string.

Here is the gulp task in Coffee:

```
# Keep a reference so that we can kill it on process.exit
leinProcess = null

# Workaround to start the Clojure frontend server.
# This is needed when running E2E tests.
gulp.task('lein-run-static', (cb) ->

  leinProcess = spawn('lein', ['run-static'])

  # Here we compare each output until the line telling us that the frontend server is
  # up running, then we know it's ready.
  leinProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) ->

    line = data.toString().trim()

    # Do not print some duplicate lines
    if !line.match(/Requiring external|Running for version|Using gulpfile/)
      # Do not use gutil.log otherwise we see double dates
      console.log(line)

    if line.match(/Started SelectChannelConnector/)
      gutil.log('Frontend server started.')
      cb()
  )

  if config.debug
    leinProcess.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)

  # Make sure null is returned otherwise gulp will interpret leinProcess as
  # a gulp task stream
  return
)
```

I'd like to use `stdio inherit` when spawning but then I will loose the ability to parse stdout.

What do you suggest here?

Comment: This is why coffeescript is so great, it makes it really easy to debug

Comment: I'm guessing wildly `data` is an object, and calling `toString` on it gives you  `[object Object]`

Comment: What is the question btw? Where the message comes from or how to set stdio? :)

Comment: Yes and no. I figured out. Data has already been converted to a string somewhere else in the code. Hence calling `toString()` on a string "[object Object]" will return `[object Object]` again. Simple.

Comment: @Heikki stdio was mentioned on a similar GitHub issue that made me ask the same question here.

Answer (score 1):

Inherit all except stdout:

```
leinProcess = spawn('lein', ['run-static'], { stdio: [0, 'pipe', 2]})
```

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio

> As a shorthand, the stdio argument may also be one of the following strings:
>
> 'pipe' - ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'], this is the default value
>
> 'ignore' - ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']
>
> 'inherit' - [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr] or [0,1,2]